# Does the domain of the real logarithm need to be "extended" when dealing with even exponents in the argument?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms

Consider $f(x)=\log(x^2)$. Clearly, the domain of $f$ is $D_f=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, since $x^2>0$ for any $x<0$. However, by the fundamental properties of logarithms:

$$
f(x)=\log(x^2)=2\log(x)\equiv g(x)
$$

where I abuse notation to give separate names $f$ and $g$ to two equivalent (but different in appearance) expressions. Clearly $f(x)\equiv g(x)$ but the domain of $g$ is $G_g=\{x\in\mathbb{R} : x>0\}\neq G_f$. How is this possible? What am I missing in the definition of a logarithm?

Note that this comes from a high-school exercise book on derivatives, so I don't think it should involve the definition of $\log(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

My take is that we define:

$$
\int\frac{1}{x}dx = \ln (|x|) + c
$$

so one must consider the argument of the logarithm as positive and/or enclosed in an absolute value operation. However, this doesn't look rigorous to me.

I have not found any similar question on this website, even though it's hard to believe no one asked it before. If I missed any useful threads, I will be happy to be redirected.

*Apologies for the abuse of notation and for poor language; I am not a native English speaker and I am relatively new to mathematical concepts. Thanks in advance for your kind answers.*

Comment: Since $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ it follows that $\log(x^2)=2\log|x|$.
The function $\log(x^2)$ is the composition of ‘square(x)’ and logarithm, in this order; so the domain of $\log(x^2)$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: To answer the question, you need to state the definition of "log" to be used.  Different definitions, used in different circumstances, may yield different answers to the question.

Comment: @Antonio thank you for the clarification, it's been very helpful.

Comment: @GEdgar what other definition of logarithm can exist in $\mathbb{R}$ though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The property $$\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$$ is only valid for $a>0$, precisely because $\log(a)$ may not even be defined.

For this reason, $f(x)=\log(x^2)$ and $g(x)=2\log(x)$ are **not** the same function, but they do agree on the set $\mathbb{R}^+$ (which is the domain of $g$).

Comment: Surprisingly simpler than I thought. Many thanks!

Comment: A secondary question: why do you say $f$ and $g$ as above defined are not the same function? Aren't they equivalent in every aspect? To me, it sounds like stating "$x\cdot x$" and "$x^2$" are different... What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f$ and $g$ don't even have the same domain, so they can't be equal (informally, you can plug values to $f$ that you cannot plug to $g$). The relation between both is that $g$ is the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: thank you very much!